# Opening up an extra web port on EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Node app running on an EC2 instance. In front of this instance is a Load Balancer. Attached the the load balancer is a security group. I have inbound rules for Port 80 and Port 443  (these are then forwarded to Port 8080 by the load balancer).

The app uses a mongo database. So now I want to setup [mongo-express](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express) to view my production database through the browser.

I've installed mongo-express on the instance and ran it on Port 8081. I then created an inbound rule for 8081 on the security group. But when I go to `http://rm-loadbalancer-xxxxxxx.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:8081` it says the site cant be reached.

Do I need to create a seperate load balancer for my mongo-express app? Or what am I forgetting?

Comment: Checkout your load Balancer documentation. If you are using ELB, check ELB documentation

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `mongo-express` configuration file https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/blob/master/config.default.js?

It is accepting connection from only local host. You can see here https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/blob/master/config.default.js#L93

You have to configure it to accept connection from anywhere(0.0.0.0) or your own IP address.